# programatically duplicate xaml control in WP

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I'm not getting how I could duplicate a XAML element pgrogramatically. For example if I define on XAML a rectangle om the middle of the screen, the user presses a button and I would like to duplicate this rectangle with all properties of it and then put it to the right of the first one, should this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - just do a deep copy of the properties you want inserted and then add it to the panel. Assuming your controls are in a StackPanel with horizontal orientation:

```
Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle()
{
    Width = oldRect.Width,
    Height = oldrect.Height,
    Stroke = oldRect.Stroke,
    // repeat for other values you want the same
};
myStackPanel.Children.Add(newRect);
```

Comment: but that's to manual :) isn't there a better way of cloning an element?

Comment: Not really. There are ways to do it via reflection but they aren't really pretty nor do they perform well. Just write a utility method to clone the types you need. There's MemberwiseClone but that's not something you can access.

Comment: ok, thanks!, I will let this question open for today, maybe another person has another idea, otherwise I will accept the answer tomorrow.

Comment: I have a problem with this. The first rectangle in XAML has the name "rectangle", If I do rectangle.Name = "oldRectangle" and then Rectangle r = new Rectangle(); r.Name = "Rectangle" and then I call Rectangle.doSomething() the first rectangle that now has the name "oldRectangle" is affected and not the new one :S

Comment: I don't believe you can change the name of a UIElement and have it automatically update references like that - those reference variables are created at run time pointing to their equivalents in XAML. You'll have to keep track of which one is "OldRectangle" and which one is "Rectangle".